# Asp.net Dynamic AXD configuration page?

Tags: asp.net

ELMAH and Glimpse I believe (when installed) expose themselves on .axd pages like site/elmah.axd.

I can't seem to find any docs on how to do this...anyone know?

Thanks,
Steve